# Why does new String() + new String() return different results under JDK8

Tags: java, string

The following codes has different results under JDK8 1.8.0_171

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    String s1 = new String("a") + new String("a");
    s1.intern();
    String s2 = "aa";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
}
@Test
public void test3() {
    String s1 = new String("1") + new String("1");
    s1.intern();
    String s2 = "11";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); //false
}
```

The only difference is the value: "a" instead of "1", the result I get is different. Why is this?

Comment: I'd not rely on `==` for string comparisons at all, i.e. whether they have been interned or not shouldn't matter. Thus the question might be moot from a practical point of view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`s1.intern()` only adds the `String` referenced by `s1` to the `String` pool if the pool doesn't already contain a `String` equal to it.

String literals such as "aa" and "11" are always interned, so they will always be `==` the instance returned by `s1.intern()`.

Therefore, whether or not `s1 == s2` returns `true` depends on whether or not the `String` pool contained a `String` equals to `s1` before `s1.intern()` was called.

- If it did, `s1.intern()` which is `== s2` is **not** `== s1`, so `System.out.println(s1 == s2)` will print `false`.
- If it did not, `s1.intern () == s1 == s2`, so `System.out.println(s1 == s2)` will print `true`.

This can change between Java versions, since JDK classes of different versions may contain a different set of `String` literals, which are automatically interned before your code is executed.

Comment: To verify this: simply adding adding a `test0` that prints (or does *anything* with) the string constant `"aa"` will make `test2` print false as well (as long as `test0` is executed before `test2`).

Comment: Clever answer. Took a few seconds to get what you were talking about.

Comment: Another thing that apparently changes between JVMs is whether literals are interned at class load time, class init time, or ... lazily the first time that a method is executed.

Comment: @ernest_k I still don't get it :( It's confusing because in `test2`, the output changes depending on whether `intern` is called or not. It seems as if `intern` "reassigns" `s1` to something else! If it were `s1 = s1.intern();`, both tests would have been true, but since the return value is ignored (`intern` merely adds the string into the string pool, but since `aa` and `11` are literals, they are already there, so `intern` does practically nothing), why does `test2` still print true?

Comment: @Sweeper: no, `intern` can't and doesn't change what `s1` is. But when a string value is first interned by use of that method, the actual instance you call `intern` on **becomes** a member of there intern pool. So instead of `intern` changing what `s1` is, it changes what `s2` will become when it will be initialized from the intern pool: either the value interned by `s1` or (if you don't call `intern`) it becomes a new string instance with the same value that is put into the intern pool instead.

Comment: @StephenC: that's what confused me as well, when I first read the question. I remember string literals being loaded at (roughly) class loading/initialization time, but apparently that's no longer true in current JVMs (if one can call JDK 8 "current" ...).

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, is the code was `s1 = s1.intern();` the result would always be true, since `s2 == s1.intern()`. If you remove the `s1.intern()` call, the result would always be false, since `s1` will never be equal to the interned instance. The difference in behavior depends on whether or not another `intern()` was called for some equal `String` (by some JDK class) prior to `s1.intern()`.

Comment: You are right. I use IDE to test them. In `test3()`, before `s1.intern()` invoke , String pool has already had String "11", so `s1.intern() ` do nothing. So s1 referenced heap instance, but s2 referenced String pool ,  the result of `s1 == s2` is false.

Comment: When I move method body to `main()` method,the result is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is to add an illustration to Eran's great answer. The following assumes `"aa"` is not interned prior to the execution of the code (implicitly or not):

```
String s1 = new String("a") + new String("a");
s1.intern();
String s2 = "aa";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true

String s3 = new String("a") + new String("a"); //same text
s3.intern();
System.out.println(s3 == s2); //false
```

Both `s1` and `s3` have the same text (`"aa"`), so the difference in actual text doesn't make the difference. The second call to `.intern()` simply didn't result in `s3` being put in the pool (because the pool already contained the text `"aa"`, which was the result of `s1.intern()`), explaining why `==` returns false between `s3` and `s2`.

In short, it means that `"11"` was interned prior to the execution of your `test3()` method.

And for an additional test, move `String s2 = "aa";` to the beginning of the code (both comparisons return `false`, for the same reason - although this may be version or implementation-dependant)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `==` operator checks if both variables reference the exact same object. For example

```
String s1 = new String("foo");
String s2 = s1;
System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
```

If you have two separate instances and you want to compare Strings based on their values you should be using `String::equals`.

```
String s1 = new String("foo");
String s2 = new String("foo");
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //true
```

Please check out [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

When it comes to `String:intern` you'd have to call it on both instances in order to compare them, not just one of them. `String foo = "foo";` still implicitly creates a new instance of a `String` object. There is no primitive `string` in Java.

```
String s1 = new String("foo");
String s2 = "foo";
System.out.println(s1.intern() == s2.intern());
```

Comment: This is the base case information. But it doesn't explain why the two tests presented by OP would produce different output and it doesn't explain why calling `s1.intern()` *without* reasinging the result back to `s1` would change the output of the test.